# Setting background color in HTML output from servlet

Tags: html, servlets

I have Servlet code like,

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Hi</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>" + "OK" + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
```

Can anybody help me, how can I define bacground color on the output html page.

Comment: *"how can I define bacground color on the output html page."* Exactly the same way you would in HTML (that was not generated by a servlet).  Note that it is better to put the styles into a stylesheet (.css) and link that into the page.  That way styles are cached across pages, and easily maintained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    out.println("<body style='background-color:#d3d3d3;'>");
```

replace #d3d3d3 with the color you want (either color name or hex color with #

Comment: I find color names to be confusing, especially if developing using IE to view the pages.  IE will interpret ***any*** string as being a color (I think it uses an algorithm based on the letters).  Other browsers typically will not.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

for example `out.println("<body bgcolor='#E6E6FA'>");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline styling on the body tag:
Instead of

```
out.println("<body>");
```

Use

```
out.println("<body bgcolor='red'>");
```

or

```
out.println("<body bgcolor=\"red\">");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can approach it this way to correct information to your servlet

```
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
out.println("<html><body bgcolor = 'yellow',text='red'><h1>Hello servlet</h1></body></html>");
```